# LeapMotion new sdk missing classes from older SDK for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I am developing an app using **leap motion** and **Unity 5.6**. Earlier I was using **LeapMotion 3.0 SDK** which was working properly in my app but had few issues which I read somewhere are fixed in the newer SDK. So I tried implementing newer sdk version **i.e 3.2.1** in my project.

I am successful in integrating SDK but there are certain classes that I was using from previous leap motion SDK but those are not present in the newer SDK version provided by leap motion, which are causing compilation error in my application.

I have searched all the unity API docs provided by Leap Motion but haven't found description on how to replace those missing classes using newer SDK.

Few classes/references that I am missing in newer SDK are:

1. **InteractionBehaviourBase**
2. **HandCollisionCallbacks**
3. **Physical Button**

I haven't found alternative classes/references for the above classes.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing classes from the beta version of the Interaction Engine. The Interaction Engine is now out-of-beta, but didn't maintain total backwards-compatibility with projects that used the beta version.

The analogous classes you're looking for would be:

1. InteractionBehaviourBase -> **InteractionBehaviour**.  The main class to refer to interactive objects is no longer InteractionBehaviourBase; it's just InteractionBehaviour.
2. HandCollisionCallbacks: This class has been removed in favor of callbacks that are accessible **through InteractionBehaviours themselves**. Here's the [API documentation for InteractionBehaviours](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/unity/class_leap_1_1_unity_1_1_interaction_1_1_interaction_behaviour.html).
3. PhysicalButton: Actually, I can't find any reference to a class with this name in Leap Motion's Unity SDK. But the new Interaction Engine provides example scenes that demonstrate how to use the new **InteractionButton** class that provides physically-simulated buttons suitable for user interfaces. Check out [Example 2](https://github.com/leapmotion/UnityModules/wiki/Getting-Started-%28Interaction-Engine%29#example-2-basic-ui-in-the-interaction-engine), "Basic UI."

For a general reference, you can find more helpful information on the new Interaction Engine via the [documentation wiki](https://github.com/leapmotion/UnityModules/wiki/Interaction-Engine).